# hyphen in rails 3 route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I would like to do the following

```
      match "company/client-list" => 'companies#list'
```

however, when I do, my routes table entry doesn't name the route, like so.

```
    /company/client-list(.:format) {:controller=>"companies", :action=>"list"}
```

as soon as I remove the hyphen in the matched route, it behaves as expected

```
    company_clientlist /company/clientlist(.:format) {:controller=>"companies", :action=>"list"}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to include hyphens in my matched routes?

Comment: What is the returned route for this one? `match "company/client-list" => 'companies#list'`? I think that this route should work, try it in your browser.

Comment: The route works if I go to it directly, but I cannot use it in a linked route...  <%= link_to "clients", company_client-list_path %> doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And I have the answer:

```
match 'company/client-list' => 'companies#list', :as => 'client_list'
```

This makes the following entry in my routes table

```
client_list /company/client-list(.:format) {:controller=>"companies", :action=>"list"}
```

Go Team!